# D/skia ( 1776): Shader compilation error, vscode and Genymotion emulator

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, genymotion

I have a simple project in flutter, everything ran fine until I tried to place an image.
Try to decrease the size, put in the terminal the command flutter run --enable-software-rendering.
Nothing has worked for me.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Material Appp'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: Image.network(
              "https://noticiasambientales.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/colibri-rdn.jpg",
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              //fit: BoxFit.cover,//default, esto es para mostrar si no cabe en el width o el height
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```